# checking (if) and selecting children/parent in jquery

Tags: jquery, parent, contains, children

My html:

```
<div class="red-box">
<h2>
<a href="#">My Cars</a>
</h2>

<div class="block_left layout2">
    <div class="part1">
        <div class="gallery_block">
            <div class="block_topic">1</div>
            <div class="block_topic">2</div>
            <div class="block_topic">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="red-box">
<h2>
<a href="#">My Bikes</a>
</h2>

<div class="block_left layout2">
    <div class="part1">
        <div class="gallery_block">
            <div class="block_topic">1</div>
            <div class="block_topic">2</div>
            <div class="block_topic">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>....
```

There are a lot of "red-box" divs with different titles in `<h2><a href="">TITLE</a></h2>`like in example above.
And I need to select and change only one  -  "red-box" -> "block_left" -> "part1" -> "gallery_block" -> "block_topic" which contains "3" and do it only in single "red-box" which got `<h2><a href="">My Cars</a></h2>`

So, I am doing following:

```
    if ($(".red-box").children("h2").children("a").children("span:contains('My Cars')").length > 0) 
    {
// it finds the "red-box" which i need but how to select
// <div class="block_topic">3</div> in the "red-box" whose href has "My Cars"?
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.red-box').has('h2:contains(My Cars)').find('div.block_topic').eq(2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L5YBf/1/

Answer (score 0):

using [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/), [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)..

try this

```
$('.red-box').has('h2:contains("My Cars")').find('div.block_topic:contains("3")');
```

`$('.red-box').has('h2:contains("My Cars")')` => gets .red-box containing "My cars".

`.find('div.block_topic:contains("3")')` =>finds div.block_topic containing 3

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't need an `if()` expression, just an appropriately phrased jQuery selection expression.

Also, particularly if the expression is to be generalized, you should avoid `:contains`, which is indiscriminate, in that it will find elements with embedded substrings matching the string of interest.

To select elements with **exactly matching** text, you can use `.filter()`, as follows :

```
$(".red-box h2 a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'My Cars';
}).closest(".red-box").find(".block_topic").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === '3';
});
```

or, if you want a `.block_topic` of known index :

```
$(".red-box h2 a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'My Cars';
}).closest(".red-box").find(".block_topic").eq(2);
```